# Webpack DefinePlugin doesn't work properly in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I am trying to set some global variables in my next app to use them as feature flags as I develop the app, and I'm generating an object with key values, and the values are strings as expected by DefinePlugin method.
Here is the next.config file I have

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
const flags = require('./src/featureFlags');

const serializedFlags = Object.keys(flags).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = JSON.stringify(flags[key]);
    return acc;
}, {});

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: (config, {webpack}) => {
        config.watchOptions = {
            poll: 1000, // Check for changes every second
            aggregateTimeout: 300, // delay before rebuilding
        };
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(serializedFlags));

        return config;
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

As I use this variable I cleared inside featureFlags.js named **FF__NEW_COMPONENT** I get the following error in the page

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: __FF_NEW_COMPONENT__ is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/pages/index.tsx (9:16) @ __FF_NEW_COMPONENT__

   7 | 
   8 | export default function Home() {
>  9 | console.log(__FF_NEW_COMPONENT__);
     |            ^
  10 | return (
  11 |     <>
  12 |         <Head>
```

I googled the issue and I couldn't find a solution! any idea how to fix this?

Thanks for taking the time to read this question!